# What would be a more efficient method to paginate through this API?

Tags: python, json, pagination, time-complexity, api-design

I created a few lines of code to paginate through an API, but with a time complexity of O(n^2), I'm curious if there is a more efficient way to implement this code.

```
#Example JSON Response
[
  {
    "internalName": "DEUSEXHUMANREVOLUTIONDIRECTORSCUT",
    "title": "Deus Ex: Human Revolution - Director's Cut",
    "metacriticLink": "/game/pc/deus-ex-human-revolution---directors-cut",
    "dealID": "HhzMJAgQYGZ%2B%2BFPpBG%2BRFcuUQZJO3KXvlnyYYGwGUfU%3D",
    "storeID": "1",
    "gameID": "102249",
    "salePrice": "2.99",
    "normalPrice": "19.99",
    "isOnSale": "1",
    "savings": "85.042521",
    "metacriticScore": "91",
    "steamRatingText": "Very Positive",
    "steamRatingPercent": "92",
    "steamRatingCount": "17993",
    "steamAppID": "238010",
    "releaseDate": 1382400000,
    "lastChange": 1621536418,
    "dealRating": "9.6",
    "thumb": "https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/238010/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1619788192"
  },
```

```
response = requests.get("https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/deals")
numPages = response.headers['X-Total-Page-Count']

entries = []

for page in range(0, int(numPages):
    url = f"https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/deals&pageNumber={page}"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    for i in range(60):
        allData = {
            'title' : data[i]['title'],
            'salePrice' : data[i]['salePrice']
        }
        entries.append(allData)
    page += 1
```

Comment: If you don’t care about order, you can make the calls in parallel

Answer (score 0):

If that's the API provided by the service, then nope -- you're as efficient as you'll get.

As an aside: I see you're doing `for i in range(60)` and guessing that there are 60 items per page? It might be better to simply iterate through all the entries in `data` instead in case the number of items per page changes over time (e.g., imagine the last page -- you might not have a full 60 items...